# Calling Clojure classes in Scala code

Tags: scala, clojure, jvm-languages

I have a simple clojure code with `project.clj` having :

```
  :uberjar-name "piezojob.jar"
  :aot :all
  :main piezo-jobs.core
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [clojurewerkz/quartzite "2.0.0"]]
```

My core.clj is :

```
(ns piezo-jobs.core
  (:require [clojurewerkz.quartzite.jobs :refer [defjob]])
  (:gen-class))

(defjob SimpleJob
  [ctx]
  (println "Running a awesome job. piezo-jobs.core."))

(defn -main []
  (println "piezo-jobs.core.-main being called."))
```

I extracted the `.jar` in my `target` folder :

```
 rm -rf extract && mkdir extract && tar -xvf piezojob.jar -C extract
```

and it shows :

```
$ tree target/extract/piezo_jobs/core
target/extract/piezo_jobs/core
└── SimpleJob.class

0 directories, 1 file
```

In my scala project, i have copied `piezojob.jar` in `lib` folder.

In one of scala file, i added :

`import piezo_jobs._`

`sbt compile` is happy.

However, if i replace it with :
`import piezo_jobs.core._` or `import piezo_jobs.core.SimpleJob`
then compiling fails with error :

```
r.scala:8: object core is not a member of package piezo_jobs
[error] import piezo_jobs.core._
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Why it is failing ?

FYI, `defjob` is a macro.

Comment: What version of Scala are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code generates both a `mynamespace.core` class and a `mynamespace.core` package. Scala doesn't like that, [see this bug report](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4695). Simply remove the `gen-class` directive from your ns definition, since all it does is generate `piezo-jobs.core.class`. Then the import should work.